# Elegant Handling Of Multiple Views For Same Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controllers

I Have a Rails app that contains a large number of resources.

The app is split into two pieces: a public facing area exists in the naked domain:

```
example.com
```

And an admin version inhabits the admin subdomain:

```
admin.example.com
```

Each of the resource controllers have the standard CRUD actions available to admin users who are signed in and are in the admin subdomain, including admin-specific views for `index` and `show` actions.

The public facing area also has `index` and `show` actions for each of the resources, but their views are *very* different form the admin view.

So I need to display different `index` and `show` views for each resource depending on subdomain.

**How can I do this whilst avoiding littering my controllers with logic operators checking the current subdomain?** It doesn't make sense to split each controllers into separate admin and public flavours because all that is different is the views that are rendered for `index` and `show`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a view folder for each sub-domain  `app/views/admin` and put all the view files for that sub-domain in it e.g. `app/views/admin/foos/index.html.erb`.

Then use the [**`prepend_view_path`**](http://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/ViewPaths/ClassMethods/prepend_view_path) to change the path based on the sub-domain like this:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :prepend_view_paths

   def prepend_view_paths
     subdomain = request.subdomain 
     prepend_view_path "app/views/#{subdomain}"
   end
 end
```

The prepend method adds the given path to front of the queue and if it is not found, it searches for the file in the default paths.

Warning: Code not tested

Comment: Nice. I'd completely missed `prepend_view_path`.